# Button with constraints inside PersonCell hides half of the button Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, constraints

Created a button inside a personCell which either shows Follow / Unfollow.
I've added the following constraints to the button:

```
Align Center Y to: Superview
Height = 43
Trailing space to: Superview
```

With or without the constraints it still cuts of a side of the button.
If the button was supposed to display "follow" it would only show "ow"

**Code for PersonCell**

```
class PersonCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!

var isFollowing: Bool?

var user: PFUser?
{
    didSet
    {
        self.configure()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.isFollowing = false
    self.followButton?.hidden = true
}

override func prepareForReuse()
{
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.isFollowing = false
    self.followButton?.hidden = true
    self.textLabel?.text = ""
    self.user = nil
}

func configure()
{
    if let constUser = user
    {
        self.textLabel?.text = constUser.username

        // are we following this person?

        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.isFollowing(constUser, completionHandler: {
            (isFollowing, error) -> () in

            if let _ = error
            {
                // Alert the user, or otherwise modify the UI
            }
            else
            {
                self.isFollowing = isFollowing

                if isFollowing == true
                {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "UnfollowButton")
                    self.followButton?.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                }
                else
                {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "FollowButton")
                    self.followButton?.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                }

                self.followButton?.hidden = false
            }

        })
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapFollow(sender: UIButton)
{
    self.followButton?.enabled = false

    let newValue = !(self.isFollowing == true)
    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.updateFollowValue(newValue, user: self.user!) { (error) -> () in

        self.followButton?.enabled = true

        let image = (newValue == true) ? UIImage(named: "UnfollowButton") : UIImage(named: "FollowButton")
        self.followButton?.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

        self.isFollowing = newValue
    }
}
```

}

Im not yet allowed to post images but see this if you need to view how it looks:

http://postimg.org/image/jnf47mnr1/

Thankx in advance!

Comment: Try to add width constraint to your button.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Still cuts it off. Just at a different spot.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni First image is the editor: (http://postimg.org/image/wo56xudgr/) and this one is the results (http://postimg.org/image/qnp4rjhk5/)

Comment: Can you share sample project so I can test?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Thanks for looking into this. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83MqvCo4QhMcWZ2RUJONzFGRmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How can I go to that cell screen?